Curve GeoNodes | Export UV attribute > Alembic
I built a geo node to create a lace that appears along a curve.
I need to export this animation to alembic to render in Keyshot. But Uv are not exported as they are a named attribute, not a mesh with proper UVs.
I'm looking for a way to get the lace with uv for each frame to build the alembic file. Does anyone has an idea?
Thanks.
